# Can I set the focal distance of android camera?

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to manual control focal distance

like this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nh_PNXD4Jqk

I already know how to use the basic function of camera.

Does everyone know how to set the focal distance by manual?

Thank you for your time and help :D

Comment: I do not know much about Cameras and so on but... Have you looked at the focusing methods and so on? With that you may be able to modify the focal distance.

[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setFocusAreas(java.util.List<android.hardware.Camera.Area>))

Comment: thank you first
I try to looked at the focusing methods, but i don't find it.

Comment: You should explicitly say that you want to adjust the focal distance *programmatically* (using code), otherwise your question will be closed as off topic.

Comment: @user1573989 did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible in versions of Android prior to Android 4.4.  In Android 4.4 there is a hidden (non-public) API to do it, but using such APIs is not recommended as they are not considered stable.  See details here: http://www.slideshare.net/lbk003/an-devcon2013-camera3kaurfinal